# Count and record partially repeating objects in objects in a new Array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to work through a source array of objects, many of the objects in the array have three property values which will be the same. It is these values that will be used to create a new object and push it on to destination array. When another object on the source array comes up with the same three property values as one of the objects on the destination array the matching object on the destination array will have its visit count incremented by one.

To help you understand, in the source array each object is a record of a meal that belongs to a user. In the second array I need to store the user details and the number of their meals.

I've tried a few solutions which have failed like the one below. I thought that the code below would create a literal object, check if it is in the destination array by finding it's indexOf (-1 for not found) and if it's not found push it on. The problem is that it never finds the objects, if I search through 3000 meals the second array ends up 3000 long!

The code below does not try to store the visit count.

```
userArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < filteredObjects.length; i++) {
    var user = { 
        forname: filteredObjects[i].forname,
        surname: filteredObjects[i].surname,
        dincat: filteredObjects[i].dincat,
    };
    var index = userArray.indexOf(user);
    if (index = -1) {
        userArray.push(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `user` object that you create in the loop is not the same as any of the objects you added inside `userArray`. They might contain the same keys and values, but strictly speaking (===) they're not the same.

To help your code, you can add a user map object:

```
var userArray = new Array(),
userMap = {};

for (var i = 0, item; item = filteredObjects[i]; ++i) {
    var userKey = item.forname + '-' + item.surname + '-' + item.dincat;

    if (!(userKey in userMap)) {
        userArray.push({
            forname: filteredObjects[i].forname,
            surname: filteredObjects[i].surname,
            dincat: filteredObjects[i].dincat,
        });
        userMap[userKey] = true;
    }
}
```

The user map is an object that uses its keys to determine whether you have already inserted a user before. This works by choosing a user identifier, in your case the combination of first name, surname and dincat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. One question, I've never seen a for loop like that before, can you explain how it works?

Comment: This is a short hand of `for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) { var item = array[N]; ... }`. At every iteration you assign `item` to the value of index `i`. At the end of the array, it will return `null` and that will also break the loop. Be careful though, this only works fine if all items in your array are non-zero (objects, non-empty strings, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

indexOf compares search element to elements of the Array using strict equality. If both operands are objects, they're compared as objects, and the equality test is true only if both refer the same object. In your case, you create a new object every time and compare it with the existing objects in the array and it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

There's several syntax errors there, but the major reason that code's not working is that what you're doing is creating a new object with the value of the object you currently at in the array loop, then looking for that new object in the array, so it's never going to be there.

I'm actually a little curious myself if there's a more efficient solution, but one possibility is

```
var demo = [
    {a: 'green', b: 'blue', c:'red'},
    {a: 'blue', b: 'green', c: 'not blue'},
    {a: 'green', b: 'blue', c: 'red'}       
],
records= {};



for (var i=0; i<demo.length; i++){
    if (records.hasOwnProperty(demo[i].a) &&
       records[demo[i].a].hasOwnProperty(demo[i].b) &&  
       records[demo[i].a][demo[i].b].hasOwnProperty(demo[i].c)
    ){
      //do something with a match
    } else {
        if (!records.hasOwnProperty(demo[i].a)) 
            records[demo[i].a] = {};

        if (!records[demo[i].a].hasOwnProperty(demo[i].b))
            records[demo[i].a][demo[i].b] = {};

        records[demo[i].a][demo[i].b][demo[i].c] = 'yes';
        //no match found
    }   
}
```

Just substitute your values in for a, b, and c and it should work.